# When to use multiplier, priority constant, aspect ratio in iOS Autolayout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have used multiplier in a place to change the view's height width depending upon the screen. And same thing happens when I used the aspect ratio as well. So, I'm lil bit confused, I can't exactly understand the difference between multiplier and aspect ratio. Can anyone explain it. And I also wanted to know about the priority constant.When should  I use it?

Comment: What Apple documentation, online totorials and videos have you looked at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Aspect Ratio` is really just a convenient way to express the `Multiplier` when working in Interface Builder. It effectively gets "converted" to a multiplier.

You can confirm this while debugging by inspecting the constraint's `.multiplier` property. If you set a view's width to `60`, and multiplier to `1:2` (resulting in an auto-layout height of `120`), the actual value of `.multiplier` will be `0.5`.

So, in my view, it depends on what *feels* more natural.

If I want a view to be 90% of the width of another view, I am much more likely to set the Multiplier to `0.9` --- which gives the exact same result as setting it to `9:10`.

However, if I want a view to maintain an aspect ration of, say, 3-to-2, I am much more likely to set the Multiplier to `3:2` rather than `1.5`.

Using a ratio can also be convenient when you have "non-simple" values. That is, it's easy to understand that a ratio of `3:2` is the same as `1.5`. But what if I have an image with native size of `281 x 60`, and I want to use those values to maintain ratio? `281:60` is easier to understand than `.multiplier = 4.68333339691162`.

And, while they are interchangeable, it is *probably* a bit more intuitive to use Ratio when constraining an object to itself - e.g. I want my view's width to be 2 x its own height, so `2:1` - and using Multiplier when constraining one object to another - e.g. I want my view's width to be 75% of the width of its superview, so `0.75`.

Comment: @DonMag..thanks . its very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Both achieves the same result. In some places you don't want to limit your UI elements width depending on that element's height or wise versa.

On that kind of situations you can define any one constraint and leave the other constraint undefined or make it an inequivalent constraint.(Ex: UILabel width is set and height can change as per content dynamically. Here you won't be going for aspect ratio).